# What is the exact source of Architecture info in lscpu command

Tags: linux, cpu, coreutils, cpu-architecture, lscpu

## Tl;dr

I need to mock info about CPU architecture on the server for testing purpose. The only way that I can achieve it, is by changing info source about CPU architecture, that is used by lscpu command (**`lscpu | grep Architecture` HAS to return mocked architecture**). I know that lscpu gets data from `/proc/cpuinfo` and `sysf`, but I cannot find **what exactly** I need to change, for lscpu to return different architecture?

## Context

I'm performing simple checks for CPU architecture used by user. I'm doing it by check like `if 'arm' =~ (lscpu | grep Architecture | awk '{print $2}')`. It's trivial check, that I want to cover. However, the issue is, that I don't know how to perform different checks for different types of architecture.

What I've tried to do:

1. Pre-preparing lscpu file with mocked `echo Architecture: <Different architecture>`
   and adding it to $PATH - tested app uses different $PATH, so it is not effective.
2. Pre-preparing lscpu file with mocked `lscpu | sed -r <expression to change Architecture>` and binding it over orginal lscpu by `sudo mount --bind <mockedlscpu> /usr/bin/lscpu` - in this case, every `lscpu` call hangs the machine.
3. Using different command than lscpu - tested app uses lscpu explicitly.

That's how I've assumed that the only way is to mock the data in /proc/cpuinfo (example output below: there's no "CPU Architecture" field):

```
processor   : 31
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 25
model       : 33
model name  : AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0xa201025
cpu MHz     : 4065.719
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 32
core id     : 15
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 31
initial apicid  : 31
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip pku ospke vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid overflow_recov succor smca fsrm
bugs        : sysret_ss_attrs spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 6787.39
TLB size    : 2560 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13] [14]
```

or sysfs, for lscpu to be ran normally and output the mocked data. However I cannot find the specific place for this CPU architecture data to change - is it possible? If yes, what is the exact place where this data is stored, and how to mock it? Every idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the source code, `lscpu` uses mainly [`uname.machine`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) to get the architecture... and some data from `cpuinfo` (flags... e.g. `lm` means long mode i.e. 64-bit etc) so no, you can't change it the way you want it (you have some limited options with `setarch`)...  I think container+qemu would be a more suitable solution...